# Using iText how do I change the distance between new lines?

Tags: java, kotlin, itext

I'm messing around with itext, and I was changing the fontsize and as a result I end up with some weirdly spaced text in my pdf:

[image]

Which I'd like to turn into something like this: (Excuse the poor image editing)

[image]

This is the code I use to enter the text:

```
private fun setBaseInfo(info: ArrayList<String>): PdfPCell
{
    val cell = PdfPCell()

    val glue = Chunk(VerticalPositionMark())
    val p = Paragraph()
    p.font.size = 8.0f

    for (str in info)
    {
        p.add(glue)
        p.add(str)
        p.add("\n")
    }

    cell.border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
    cell.addElement(p)

    return cell
}
```

And this is the info I feed it:

```
private fun foo(): ArrayList<String>
{
    val array = ArrayList<String>()
    array.add("Hi")
    array.add("StackOverflow")
    array.add("I'd Like")
    array.add("This")
    array.add("text")
    array.add("to be closer")
    array.add("together!")
    return array
}
```

When removing `p.add("\n")` this is the output:
[image]

Comment: You add `glue` (`VerticalPositionMark`) inbetween each line, is this not what's creating the space you're seeing?

Comment: The glue is for aligning it to the rightmost side I thought?

Comment: From [VerticalPositionMark](https://coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/pdf/draw/VerticalPositionMark.html): "*Can be used to add horizontal or vertical separators. Won't draw anything unless you implement the draw method.*", so I think you're creating horizonal seperators? Not sure though, what happens if you remove it?

Comment: Removing the glue only changes the position back to the left side of the page, it doesn't change the spacing unfortunately.

Comment: If you remove the `add("\n")` part it's not fixed either? `add` with `String` as argument to a `Paragraph` creates a `Chunk` wrapper internally which might already include a new line or padding

Comment: If I remove the add("\n") I get this (see post edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full disclosure: former iText employee here

This is how I would do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // create a temp file to hold the output
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile("stackoverflow",".pdf");

    PdfDocument pdfDocument =  new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

    String[] lines = {"Hi","StackOverflow","I'd like","this","text","to","be","closer","together!"};
    for(String line : lines){
        layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph(line)
                .setMultipliedLeading(0.5f));   // this is where the magic happens
    }

    layoutDocument.close();
    pdfDocument.close();

    // display the temp file with the default PDF viewer
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(outputFile);
}
```

I changed a couple of things:

- Use the latest version of iText whenever possible. You want to benefit from several years of bugfixes and a newer architecture.
- Do not use tables to solve layout issues.
- Use leading (either MultipliedLeading or FixedLeading) on Paragraph objects to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know I should use the most recent version, but this is just a version I had laying around as I wanted to mess about a little bit, appreciate the help a lot! Tables are a crutch indeed, but they are really useful, but I agree I should stop using them.